# Azure Api Management Rewrite Url

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm testing out an api request in Azure Api Management.

The request comes in like this...

azure-api.net/v1/subscriptions?subscriptionId=ac70f43a-29c5-448f-b723-0536ab409a61

And sent to my backend api like this...

azurewebsites.net/api/v1/subscriptions/subscriptions?subscriptionId=ac70f43a-29c5-448f-b723-0536ab409a61

I need it to be truncated and rewritten like this...

azurewebsites.net/api/v1/subscriptions/subscriptions/ac70f43a-29c5-448f-b723-0536ab409a61

How can I configure this?

Comment: I think you need to use the url rewrite template https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#RewriteURL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the rewrite transformation policy 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#RewriteURL